# save string to variable, gets builtin_function error

Tags: python

Im trying to save 5 names to a variable , but i get error

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment
```

I have tried a couple of other method but with no luck, and i cant seem to see where the problem is.

```
k = 0 
while k < 5: 
    sum = input("name: ") 
    ord[k] = sum 
    k += 1
```

Comment: Why are you storing an input result for a name in a variable called `sum`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker maybe the OP speaks [Latin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sum#Latin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm trying to save 5 names to a variable

Not the best description. Better: "I'm trying to create a dictionary with 5 strings in it."

> but i get an error

[`ord` is a built in function](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#ord). It is not a dictionary, unless you have assigned to this name before (You don't have `ord = {}` in your code). Certain IDEs, like the [PyDev](http://pydev.org/download.html) plugin for eclipse, would have warned you about such errors.

Pick another name, and initialize it:

```
d = {}
k = 0 
while k < 5: 
    s = input("name: ") 
    d[k] = s
    k += 1
```

([`sum` is a built-in too](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sum).)

If you are using python2.x, you should use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

---

This code, by the way, can be written like this:

```
d = {}
for k in range(5): 
    d[k] = input("name: ")
```

or even shorter:

```
d = { k:input('name: ') for k in range(5) }
```

and since the indices are 0..4, why not use a simple `list` ?

```
d = [ input('name: ') for _ in range(5) ]
```

Comment: I have been hassle with this for a long time now.
THANK YOU